# Problems configuring JCS remote auxiliary

Tags: jcs

I'm new to JCS and currently trying to configure JCS ver 1.3 Remote auxiliary.

Both my client and server cache.ccf are almost equivalent to the [samples provided here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/RemoteAuxCache.html).

Note that my server is configured to run at localhost: 1104.

The moment my client starts up, the server logs start throwing the below error.
Not really sure what is wrong with the configuration. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
INFO: Constructed cache with name [cacherepl] and cache attributes [ useLateral = true, useRemote = true, useDisk = true, maxObjs = 100, maxSpoolPerRun = -1, diskUsagePattern = 0 ]
Jun 10, 2014 3:13:31 PM org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.remote.server.RemoteCacheServer get
SEVERE: Problem getting listeners.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:221)
    at org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheConfigurator.parseRegion(CompositeCacheConfigurator.java:321)
    at org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheConfigurator.parseRegion(CompositeCacheConfigurator.java:283)
    at org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager.getCache(CompositeCacheManager.java:448)
    at org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager.getCache(CompositeCacheManager.java:387)
    at org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager.getCache(CompositeCacheManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.remote.server.RemoteCacheServer.getCacheListeners(RemoteCacheServer.java:174)
    at org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.remote.server.RemoteCacheServer.get(RemoteCacheServer.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
```

Comment: We ended up using infinispan instead. Got all that we were looking for, from JCS.